# Is there a Kotest assertion to test if a list contains some element with a given property?

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, kotest

I have two objects that have some features in common that I would like to compare

```
data class Pet(val colour: String, val owner: Human, val legCount: Int)
data class Car(val colour: String, val owner: Human, val isElectric: Boolean)
```

I would like to assert that some element in a `List<Car>` contains an element with the same colour and owner as a given `Pet`.

Here's a fake code example to illustrate what I'm trying to do:

```
cars.containsElementSatisfying { car ->
    pet.colour shouldBe car.colour
    pet.owner shouldBe car.owner
}
```

How might I do this using kotest? I can accomplish the desired functionality using assertJ's anySatisfy assertion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the solution. The "Inspectors" kotest library contains a number of functions similar to assertJ's `anySatisfy` assertion, in particular the collection functions `forAtLeastOne` and `forAtLeast(k)`

Here's example usage:

```
cars.forAtLeastOne { car -> 
    pet.colour shouldBe car.colour
    pet.owner shouldBe car.owner
}
```

https://kotest.io/docs/assertions/inspectors.html